# Automatic date selection onselect another date textbox with "add a row" functionality

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to display a date for another date field with date selected of current field. It's working perfectly only for the first row. Below is the code:

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){

$('.one').datepicker({
onSelect: function(date){
  var date2 = $('.one').datepicker('getDate');
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
  $('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);
}
})
$('.two').datepicker({})

});
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentItem = 1;
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
$('#addnew').click(function(){
currentItem++;
$('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td style=""><input type="text" name="task'+currentItem+'" id="task'+currentItem+'" value="" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" name="Description'+currentItem+'" id="Description'+currentItem+'" value="" /></td><td style="width: 160px;"><input type="text" class="one datepicker" name="Internal_Deadline'+currentItem+'" id="Internal_Deadline'+currentItem+'" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" class="two datepicker" name="Client_Deadline'+currentItem+'" id="Client_Deadline'+currentItem+'" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="Actual_Deadline'+currentItem+'" id="Actual_Deadline'+currentItem+'" /></td><td style="width:83px;"></td></tr>';
 $('#data').append(strToAdd);
   $(".datepicker").datepicker(); 

  });
  });

  //]]>

  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<TABLE id="data" class="dd" style="">
    <TR>
    <td style=""><input type="text" name="task1" id="task1" value="" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" name="Description1" id="Description1" value="" /></td><td style="width: 160px;"><input type="text" class="one datepicker" name="Internal_Deadline1" id="Internal_Deadline1" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" class="two datepicker" name="Client_Deadline1" id="Client_Deadline1" value="" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="Actual_Deadline1" id="Actual_Deadline1" value="" />             </td><td style="width: 83px;"></td></tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" /> 
    </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to late-bind in order to events to work on DOM elements that will be added later:

```
    $(function () {

        $('.one').datepicker();

        $('#data').on('change', '.one', function (date) {                
            var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);                
            $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);                                
        });

        $('.two').datepicker();

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is to automatically display date on all Client_Deadline1 fields. <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add a Row" /> is to add the rows

Comment: One issue. Now, the new date is updating in all Client_Deadline1. Eg: If i'm selecting 5th feb it's automatically displaying 6th feb and then when i'm adding a row and selecting a date that previous value also get's updated with the new date.

Comment: If you want it to update only the second datepicker in the same row, I 've updated my answer. Please rate and accept it as answer if it was what you were looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One more help if you can: I would like to add the new date with 1 bussiness days. For example if user select any friday, it should display monday's date in the Client_Deadline field